# Unable to make a sprite from a URL in UI Thread in Andengine Android

Tags: android, image, andengine, game-engine

Please see the below code.

```
Activity ac= (Activity)cxt;

    ac.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            load();
        }
    });
```

This is constructor where I am calling a function to load a sprite from a URL. The function is below

```
private void load()
{

    if(isInternetOn()){
        try {
            ITexture mTexture = new BitmapTexture(mEngine.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {

                    URL url = new URL("http://tenlogix.com/cupcakemania/Ads/burgermaker.png");

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input);    
                    return in;
                }
            });
            mTexture.load();
            MyImageFromWeb = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mTexture);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TenlogixAds"," "+e);
        }

        AdSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, MyImageFromWeb, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TenlogixAds"," No Internet Connection Detected.. ");
        AdSprite = null;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the image is loaded if I call the load function now in UI Thread but its not loaded when I call it in UI Thread.

Calling it in UI Thread is important because I want to do this task is background with causing issues to the game running.

I have also tried AsyncTask but the problem I described with UI Thread is same with Async Task.

Can any one help me with this problem?

I want to load an image from web, and I want it to be loading in background with causing any delay or issues to game being played.

Comment: use Async Task bro, Because when it called the UI thread is not restore the call.But Async reply you if it get response from previous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use Async Task also debug the value mTexture is not null.

```
public void loadImageFromServer() {

    final IAsyncCallback callback = new IAsyncCallback() {

        @Override
        public void workToDo() {
            Log.e("BaseActivity", "OnWhat to do working");
            if (isInternetOn()) {
                try {
                    ITexture mTexture = new BitmapTexture(
                            mEngine.getTextureManager(),
                            new IInputStreamOpener() {
                                @Override
                                public InputStream open()
                                        throws IOException {

                                    URL url = new URL(
                                            "http://tenlogix.com/cupcakemania/Ads/burgermaker.png");

                                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                            .openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    connection.connect();
                                    InputStream input = connection
                                            .getInputStream();
                                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                                            input);
                                    return in;
                                }
                            });
                    if (mTexture != null) {
                        mTexture.load();

                        MyImageFromWeb = TextureRegionFactory
                                .extractFromTexture(mTexture);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("TenlogixAds", " " + e);
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("TenlogixAds", " No Internet Connection Detected.. ");
                AdSprite = null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // can create after Initializing MyImageFromWeb

            if (MyImageFromWeb != null) {

                AdSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, MyImageFromWeb,
                        mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            }

        }

    };

    aBaseActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AsyncTaskLoader().execute(callback);
        }
    });

}
```

**IAsyncCallback** is an Interface. Looks Like:

```
    public interface IAsyncCallback {
    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================
    public abstract void workToDo();

    public abstract void onComplete();

}
```

And My **AsyncTaskLoader** class is Like:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class AsyncTaskLoader extends
        AsyncTask<IAsyncCallback, Integer, Boolean> {
    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================
    IAsyncCallback[] _params;

    // ===========================================================
    // Inherited Methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(IAsyncCallback... params) {
        this._params = params;
        int count = params.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            params[i].workToDo();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        int count = this._params.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this._params[i].onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are calling load(); method on UI Thread which freeze UI Thread until Network Operation is not complete. for getting image in background thread you will need to call load(); outside of `runOnUiThread` as:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
         // call  load() method here
           load();
          ac.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update image here without interrupting user
                  .....
            }
        });
      }
}).start();
```

Comment: But he wants delay and issues in his game :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not professional of Andengine. Hope that I can help you :D

I wirte some app before using online resource will cache the file first using the cache storage method in android.

you can save file to Conetext.getCacheDir ()
and System will automatic release the memory after the application unload.

[public abstract File getCacheDir ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29)

Further Information.
Using HttpURLConnection to download image
You can use fileoutputStream to save image

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Context.getCacheDir() + "/my_image.png"));
    fos.write(.....);
    fos.flush();
```

Then you can normally use the image from Context.getCacheDir() + "/my_image.png"

Comment: this is not my problem. My problem is delay while loading image from URL.

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding your question :D

You can use Android asynctask || runOnUiThread,
I always use asynctask for loading resource.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html